# FlatList does not pass through 0 or null into renderItem prop

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

If I try to render a FlatList like so:

```
<View>
   <FlatList
     numColumns={2}
     data={[1, 0, 3, null]}
     renderItem={(itemData, idx) => <Text key={idx}>{itemData.item}</Text>}
     horizontal={false}
   />
</View>
```

The only thing returned would be `1` and `2` (except they take up space in the row/column as if the other values had rendered as well–they stack up in a column). I have no access to the `0` value or the `null` value (so I can't conditionally render something else, i.e. `return itemData.item || 'No Data'`.

If I try this (with slightly less props):

```
<View>
    <FlatList
      data={[1, 0, 3, null]}
      renderItem={(itemData, idx) => <Text key={idx}>{itemData.item}</Text>}
    />
</View>
```

I get an error `Invariant Violation: No item for index 2`.

Is there a solution besides looping through the data beforehand and replacing all `0`'s with a string `"0"` and all `null`s, `undefined`, empty strings etc. with a string `"null"` and conditionally rendering with that: `return itemData.item !== 'null' ? itemData.item || 'No Data'`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when you try to access `itemData.0` it understands as `false` instead of number `0`, the same logic looks to be applied when trying to access `itemData.null` value.

If you add a `console.log` to your renderItem, you can confirm if what I said is correct

```
renderItem={(itemData, idx) => {
  console.log('Trying to render item: ', idx);
  return <Text key={idx}>{itemData.item}</Text>;
}}
```

Supposing this is the case, then you can achieve what you want by something like this:

`renderItem={(itemData, idx) => itemData.item && <Text key={idx}>{itemData.item}</Text>}`

Hope it helps